# Can a process terminate after I/O without returning to the CPU?

Tags: process, operating-system

I have a question about the following diagram from *Operating Systems Concepts*: http://unboltingbinary.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image028.jpg

This diagram seems to imply that after every I/O operation, the process is placed back on the ready queue before being sent to the CPU again. However, is it possible for a process to terminate after I/O but before being sent to the ready queue?

Suppose we have a program that computes a number and then writes it to storage. In this case, does the process really need to return to the CPU after the I/O operation? It seems to me that the process should be allowed to terminate right after I/O. That way, there would be no need for a context switch.

Comment: More often than not, a process might wish to clean up before terminating, that is, free memory, release resources such as memory mappings and open files or sockets.

Comment: Don't see why not. If all the process threads are stuck on I/O or inter thread comms, it would make the process easier to terminate - no threads running on cores to stop, (assuming out-of-process termination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once one process has successfully executed a termination request on another, the threads of the terminated process should never run again, no matter what state they were in - blocked on I/O, blocked on inter-thread comms, running on a core, sleeping, whatever - they all must be stopped immediately if running and all be put in a state where they will never run again.

Anything else would be a security issue - terminated threads should not be given execution at all, (else it may not be possible to terminate the process).

Answer (score 0):

Process termination requires the cpu.  Changes to kernel mode structures on process exit, returning memory resources, etc. all require the cpu.

A process simply just does not evaporate.  The term you want here is process rundown - I think.

Comment: 'Process termination requires the cpu' - sure, but it does not need to be the threads of the terminated process that are using the CPU.  In fact, that must not happen.

Comment: Well 'End Process' from the Windows Task Manager, or 'kill -9', does a pretty good job of evaporating the process.

Comment: Thank you Martin and Jim for your responses. I have a further question. which results in better system performance: having processes terminate themselves or having processes be terminated by other processes?

Comment: Answer: neither one.  You need to read up on system wait calls (process exit()), and system signals (another process terminates signal() ) to understand why your question does not have a direct answer.  The kernel in some circumstances can also terminate a process.  SIGSEGV signal is an example.

Comment: ^ yes.  In general, it's easier if a process requestes its own termination - one running thread, (the one calling for termination), has already entered the kernel and so put itself in a position where it can be terminated with little further effort, whereas an out-of-process termination. does not have that guarantee:  Stopping threads running on other cores is a lengthier operation involving an inter-core driver and hardware interrupt to force the other threads to enter the kernel and then die.

Comment: @Martin is correct but we have a different definition of easy.  Assuming one thread, the amount of code and resoruces required to terminate a process is slightly less for SIGSEGV than for a call to exit().  Why? A lot more cleanup of resources is required for orderly process termination for exit() than for SIGSEGV assuming no core dump.  In fact see Stevens 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment' 2nd Edition for more details.